# getting Preconnect to required origins error in Lighthouse

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, pagespeed, lighthouse

I just moved my static website to AWS S3 + Cloudfront & Route 43. Once I deployed my site I ran Lighthouse & Pagespeed Insights and I'm getting "Preconnect to required origins Error!".
[image]
Before I moved my site I was not getting this error, so I'm thinking it has something to do with my AWS configuration. Here is my preconnects in my index.html file.

```
<link rel="preconnect" href="//www.google-analytics.com" crossorigin>
<link rel="preconnect" href="//fonts.googleapis.com" crossorigin>
<link rel="dns-prefetch" href="//fonts.googleapis.com">
```

I'm not connecting to any other 3rd parties, only Analytics & Google font. Am I missing a preconnect to cloudfront? I searched for a couple days online and have not found anything yet, so I'm here.

Answer (score 1):

If you make requests directly to your Cloudfront domain, then you will need to preconnect to it too.

I'm not positive but should your `href` tag values start with `https`?